# AFNetworking give me unauthorised error

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, afnetworking

That is my first time that I am using`AFNetworking` in my app. I've installed the latest version (3.0) using pods .  Now the problem is the url is working fine in browser and postman but when I get try in app it gives me unauthorised error. I don't know how to authorise. I am adding username and password in header. Can any body help me.
Bellow is my code.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:username forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];


[manager GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    success(responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    failure(error);

}];
```

Following is full error log

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"
 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa1c3f945b0 {Error
 Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request
> failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"
> UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse:
 0x7fa1c3d139f0> { URL:
 http://192.168.0.111/guesswhat/getcategories.json } { status code:
 401, headers {
         "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
         Connection = "Keep-Alive";
         "Content-Length" = 89;
        "Content-Type" = "text/html";
         Date = "Mon, 11 Jan 2016 12:30:55 GMT";
         Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
         "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=99";
         Pragma = "no-cache";
         Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19";
         "Www-Authenticate" = "Digest realm=\"Restricted area\",qop=\"auth\",nonce=\"5693a07f60c93\",opaque=\"cdce8a5c95a1427d74df7acbf41c9ce0\"";
 Blockquote     "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.19"; } },
```

Comment: Please post error console log, so we will find some solution.

Comment: Seems like you don't have access or pure credentials are not correct

Comment: Recheck values of `username/password`.

Comment: the username/password is correct. Its woking in postaman.

Comment: try printing [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[error.userInfo objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:4]

Comment: I think you are using GET where,as you should use the POST method of AFNetworking library

Comment: in post man are you sure setting http headers or setting request parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code send your parameter in NSDictionary.(There is no base url in your code also passing parameter nil).

```
    NSDictionary *parameters;
    ///// HTTP GET REQUEST TO DELETE ARTWORK
        parameters = @{@"device_user_id": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserID"],
                       @"device_auth_key": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AuthKey"],
                       @"query":@"",
                       @"user_id":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[[self.otherUserDictionary objectForKey:@"from_user"] objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]],
                       @"mobile_request":@"yes"};
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL_STRING]];//Here your base url string
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer =[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers];
//   /search replace accordingly
    [manager GET:@"/search" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary* responseObject) {

        //NSLog response object
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: We can use full url without specifying the base URL also it is possible to send nil in request parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try to set value for "Authorization" field  on request serializer.

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"AuthToken" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of this :

NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

format Content-Type" = "text/html doesn't have your AFNetworking.

**so simply go to** Serilization->**AFURLResponseSerialization.m**, line 215, and change it:

**self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];**

it will work for you.

More recent versions may have the code on line 223

Comment: if you want to change this no need to edit original source, you can use manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:];

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your request formation. Based on the error log, please set the request content type, auth header and http method type. Services mostly use base64 string for user name and password auth field
     example code:

```
    //base 64 auth value from username and password
    - (void)setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:(NSString *)username
                                           password:(NSString *)password
    {
        NSString *basicAuthCredentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
        [self setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", AFBase64EncodedStringFromString(basicAuthCredentials)] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    }
  // authValue is your base 64 string from username and password
     [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
     [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
      manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```